# Is this static dictionary field thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

This is Asp.net MVC Web Project.

I'm preparing "user tree" on every 30 seconds. (RefreshUsers method) So set operation is atomic. 
Get operation is multi-threaded.

Is this approach thread safe?

```
public static class InternalCache
{
    private static Dictionary<long, UserModel> _Users;

    public static RefreshUsers(){
        //.............
        // var res=.......
        _Users= res;
    }

    public static UserModel GetUser(long id){
        return _Users[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading Jon Skeet's [post on the singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx). It helps you understand different implementations of thread safety and laziness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can ensure that only one thread calls your `RefreshUsers` function at a time, then yes, your code should be thread-safe.

Otherwise you would have to make the functions thread-safe:

In order to make a function thread safe you will need an object to lock:

```
private static object _lockObj = new Object();
```

Then lock that object when you write to your `_Users` and also when you get it:

```
public static class InternalCache
{
    private static Dictionary<long, UserModel> _Users;
    private static object _lockObj = new Object();

    public static RefreshUsers(){
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            //.............
            // var res=.......
            _Users= res;
        }
    }

    public static UserModel GetUser(long id){            
        return _Users[id];            
    }
}
```

The lock ensures that everything inside the lock-block is only beeing accessed by one thread at a time as the thread locks that object as soon as it reaches the line `lock(...)`. So when the next thread reaches this line he can't lock that object and waits until the other thread has released the lock.

Comment: 1- Is Lock cost too high with this implemantation? 2-If I use lock why i dont use ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: @ozz `ConcurrentDictionary` is lock-free. Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548406/Dictionary-plus-Locking-versus-ConcurrentDictionar)

Comment: @ozz it's worth noting that ConcurrentDictionary wouldn't make RefreshUsers thread safe. But it would make reads and writes to the collection members thread safe. If you don't need that then it's pointless.

Comment: Thanks i got it. But Is 1000 GetUser Calls per Second serious performance penalty with this implemantation? Could you suggest better way?

Comment: @ozz, you could remove the lock from the GetUser function. However thiw will cause the client to load the old user when RefreshUsers is in progress.

Comment: No problem with it. The question is during "_Users= res;" command does anyone get exception?

Comment: Because set operation is atomic. There is no need to lock RefreshUsers method also I think.

Comment: No, you shouldn't get any exception

Comment: So could you correct your answer.. My implemantation is thread-safe ?

Comment: If you can ensure that only one thread calls your `RefreshUsers` function at a time, then yes.

Comment: By not locking in `GetUser` it's possible that threads will not see the latest version of `_Users`

Comment: There is no problem to see old values. Seeing null or getting exception is problem.

Answer (score 3):

Although the setting of the static variable is atomic you are still running the risk that compiler optimizations and instruction re-ordering may lead to certain threads seeing stale values for `_Users`.

To remove this you need to either use a `lock` whenever you access the static variable or use the `Interlocked` functions to read/write the variable:

```
public static class InternalCache
{
    private static Dictionary<long, UserModel> _Users;


    public static RefreshUsers()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _Users, res);
    }

    public static UserModel GetUser(long id)
    {            
        // Read the variable, ensuring we always see the latest value
        var users = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _Users, null, null);
        return users[id];            
    }
}
```

Comment: Useful answer. But I don't have problem with seeing old values(stale values). Period of Refreshing is 30 seconds. So seeing old values is not primary issue for this scenerio. The performance is more important concern. Thanks.